# how to replace this.$refs in composition API

Tags: vuejs3, ref

How to replace this.$refs in composition API.
I have PostComponent:

```
<script setup>
import CreateComponent from "./CreateComponent.vue";
import IndexComponent from "./IndexComponent.vue";
</script>
<template>
    <div >
        <create-component />
        <index-component ref="index"  />
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

and IndexComponent:

```
<script setup>
    const indexLog = () => {
        console.log('this is index component');
    }
    </script>
    <template>
        <div >
                <h1> Bla Bla <h1>
        </div>
    </template>
```

in option API when I want to get text from IndexComponent indexLog function it is simple I wrote this.$refs.index.indexLog() in PostComponent mounted:

```
mounted(){
    console.log(this.$refs.index.indexLog())
}
```

and I got this in console:

```
this is index component
```

but how to get the same functionality with vuejs 3 and script setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `ref` on that child component. Here's the example:

```
<script setup>
import CreateComponent from "./CreateComponent.vue";
import IndexComponent from "./IndexComponent.vue";
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const child = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  // child.value will hold an instance of <Child />
  console.log(child.value.indexLog())
})
</script>
<template>
    <div >
        <create-component />
        <index-component ref="child"  />
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

In the child component, you have to expose the value that you want to give the parent access to, like this:

```
<script setup>
    const indexLog = () => {
        console.log('this is index component');
    }
   // Compiler macros, such as defineExpose, don't need to be imported
   defineExpose({
     indexLog
   })
    </script>
    <template>
        <div >
                <h1> Bla Bla <h1>
        </div>
    </template>
```

You can check out the official vue docs for referencing child component [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component)